# Is this a defensive addition? ".SynchronizingObject =this;"

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, multithreading

I'm testing the following and trying to understand what it does to then apply it to me live app. The app seems to work with or without `.SynchronizingObject = this;`. I've looked [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.synchronizingobject.aspx) but could do with an alternative explanation of what this line does and why I need to include it?

```
private void btRunProcessAndRefresh_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    //instantiate a new process and tell it where to find file 
    myProcess =new Process();
    myProcess.StartInfo.FileName =@"notepad.exe";

    //creates an action to execute when the event exits  
    myProcess.Exited +=new EventHandler(MyProcessExited);
    myProcess.EnableRaisingEvents =true;

    //myProcess.SynchronizingObject =this;
    elapsedTime = 0;
    myProcess.Start();

    myTimer =new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
    myTimer.Tick +=new EventHandler(TimerTickEvent);
    myTimer.Interval = SLEEP_AMOUNT;
    myTimer.Start();
}

private void MyProcessExited(Object source,EventArgs e) {
    myTimer.Stop();
}

private void TimerTickEvent(Object myObject,EventArgs myEventArgs) {
    myTimer.Stop();
    elapsedTime += SLEEP_AMOUNT;
    if (elapsedTime > MAXIMUM_EXECUTION_TIME)
        myProcess.Kill();
    else
        myTimer.Start();
}
```

Comment: To respond correctly you should show your MyProcessExited method. The SynchronizingObject is needed to assure that your _MyProcessExited_ method will be called on the same thread of your form. Otherwise you need to take extra actions if you plan to change something in you UI inside that method.

Comment: URL to local MSDN makes no sense at all.

Comment: @steve - I'll present full code now

Comment: @abatishchev: ok I'll correct; oh you've already edited - thanks

Comment: I suppose that having only `myTimer.Stop();` in MyProcessExited will not cause any adverse effect. However I will stay with `myProcess.SynchronizingObject =this;` uncommented, just to be safe.

Comment: (lol) didn't think that'd be spotted; no I don't; I'll change the link back to what you edited it to earlier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.synchronizingobject.aspx)

> You should set SynchronizingObject to a Windows Form component to ensure the Exited event handler executes in the thread that created the component.

If you execute your code sequence in a console application than you probably do not need to set the SynchronizingObject; but if you want to access the UI from the Exited event handler, you must set this member.

Comment: so in my code it'll ensure that I return to the thread with the form